# How to import Greendroid library step by step?

Tags: android, google-maps, greendroid

can anyone teach me how to import greendroid library to our eclipse?
especially to our project step by step.
i'am still beginner for this library. thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GreenDroid is a library developed by [Cyril Mottier](https://plus.google.com/+CyrilMottier/posts). I know GreenDroid is a development library for the Android platform and intended to make UI developments easier and consistent through your applications.

But you should read statement given on GitHub:

> Foreword : This project, initially initiated by me, Cyril Mottier, is
>   not maintained anymore and can be considered as deprecated. As a
>   consequence, it will not receive any new features nor fixes. Please
>   keep that in mind and use it at your own risks.

So **I don't suggest you to use this library** but if your purpose of using this library to make your UI consistent through the applications and android platforms then there are many other libraries available:

1. [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) by [Jack Wharton](https://plus.google.com/+JakeWharton/posts) (or you can use AppCompat by Google to provide compatibility to lower versions)
2. Google Maps API v2, for displaying and using Maps in Android. Map API is became very polished and one greatness of this API is its with top level abstraction so you won't need to write much code for displaying map or marker or directions or anything.

Let me know if you want any guidance for anything regarding UI!